# AngularJs email validation error

Tags: angularjs

I have two email address

> example@gmail.com

and

> example@somevalue

both the email address are valid when I use the AngularJs validation

```
<input type="email" ng-model="application.email_id" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
```

I need to make example@somevalue mail address as false if the address is wrong.

[This](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) is the tutorial part of AngularJs email validation: there the validation is true when I inputing the above email address.

Comment: What do you mean by "make.. address as false *if the address is wrong*"?  What does "wrong" mean here.

Comment: @New Dev : it seems to be an invalid email address (xyz@xyz), since it does not have any domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ng-pattern="" with your custom pattern to validate the email. 
In your controller:

```
$scope.pattern = /.+\@.+\..+/;
```

In your HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" ng-pattern="pattern" required>
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vszMaSYmnXhsMUSW2eLJ) (the example from the angular documentation extended with ng-pattern)

Comment: I think that the right way is to use ng-pattern but i would go for a more [complete regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: thank you very much.....its working